# Real-life math problem , how much faster did i run?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

So I was running today and I tried to run faster than usual.
I always workout for $30$ minutes, which contains $25$ minutes of running and $5$ minutes of walking.
But today, I ran $20$ minutes and walked for $10$.
The distance in both workouts was the same, but I'm not sure of the absolute value of it. I'm assuming the same walking speed for both workouts.
So I was wondering, is it possible to know how much faster was I running today in percentage or in absolute value?
Meaning get an answer in form of
$V_1=aV_2$ or $V_1=V_2+a$

I figured there are not enough data, so I tried to assume $6$ km/hour, walking speed, but still couldn't get a result.

Bonus:
This really happened to me

Comment: @45465 edited the post

Comment: Thanks for the editing and the re-tagging

Comment: Try running longer for better helath ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume constant speed both during walking and running separately, that is, no acceleration. And, as you say, let us use walking speed as $6km/hr=\frac{5}{3}$ meter/sec. Now, in your usual routine, we have $(25\times 60)v_1+300\times\frac{5}{3}$ as the total distance, where $v_1$ is the initial running distance. In the second case, that is today, we have $(20v_2\times 60)+600\times\frac{5}{3}$ as the total distance. Thus, equating the distances as you said they are equal, we obtain $300(5v_1+\frac{5}{3})=600(2v_2+\frac{5}{3})\implies 5v_1=4v_2+\frac{5}{3}$ in meter/sec

Comment: Since it  cant be determent how much faster did i ran, Is there perhaps a way to say i run at least 10% faster but not faster 20% or somthing of this sort?

Comment: @EliDayan no, for that we require the value of either $v_1$ or $v_2$

Answer (score 0):

Your walk speed is $v_0$ your normal run speed is $v_1$ but today it was $v_2$.

Normally you exersice the distance $s=5v_0+25v_1$.

Today you exersiced the same distance $s=10v_0+20v_2$.

So, what you have is $5v_0+25v_1=10v_0+20v_2\Leftrightarrow v_2=\frac{25v_1-5v_0}{20}$.

So, if for example $v_0=100$ (that is 100m per minute or 6km per hour) then $v_2=\frac{25v_1-500}{20}$.

You need $v_1$ (or $v_2$) in meters per minute. Or then you need to know the total distance $s$ in meters.

Answer (score 0):

If your two running speeds were $r_1$ and $r_2$ and your walking speed was $w$ then $$25r_1+5w=20r_2+10w$$

That could be rewritten as something like $$r_2=\tfrac54r_1-w$$ or $$r_2-r_1 =\tfrac14(r_1-w)$$ or $$\frac{r_2}{r_1}=\frac54-\frac{w}{r_1}$$or something similar but not much simpler than that

Comment: So it appear there is no answer to the question in the form that i thought of. But is there a proof there isn't

Comment: @EliDayan you have one equation in three unknowns (or two simultaneous equations in four unknowns which can be simplified to one equation in three unknowns).  So there is a two-dimensional solution set while you want a one-dimensional solution set.